# How to manage Label in c#

Tags: c#, textbox, label

I am trying to organize Label and TextBoxes in c# i have two function :

```
private void BtnKaydet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _service = new Client.BioAuthenticationService.BioAuthenticationService();
    int warningcase = 0;

    if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(TbTcNo.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TbTcNo.Text)))
    {
        warningcase = 1;
        TextLabelManagement(warningcase);                              
    }
    else if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(TbId.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TbId.Text)))
    {
        warningcase = 2;
        TextLabelManagement(warningcase);               
    }
    else if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(TbName.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TbName.Text)))
    {
        warningcase = 3;
        TextLabelManagement(warningcase);      
    }
    else if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(TbSurname.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TbSurname.Text)))
    {
        warningcase = 4;
        TextLabelManagement(warningcase); 
    }
    else if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(TbDepartment.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TbDepartment.Text)))
    {
        warningcase = 5;
        TextLabelManagement(warningcase);
    }

    else
    {
        if (_imageIndex == 3)
        {
            bool enrollResult = _service.CheckAndEnrollUser(image1, image2, image3, 300, 6);
        }
        else
        {
            warningcase = 6;
            TextLabelManagement(warningcase);
        }
    }
}
```

Here i write cases if TextBox is null i will give error message to fill them. Here is my cases :

```
private void TextLabelManagement(int cases)
{
    switch (cases)
    {
        case 1:
            LblWarning.Visible = true;
            LblWarning.Text = "* Lütfen Bu Alanları Doldurunuz..";
            LblTcNo.Text = "* TC No";
            LblTcNo.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            LblWarning.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red; 
            break;
        case 2:
            LblWarning.Visible = true;
            LblWarning.Text = "* Lütfen Bu Alanları Doldurunuz..";
            LblId.Text = "* ID";
            LblId.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            LblWarning.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            break;
        case 3:
            LblWarning.Visible = true;
            LblWarning.Text = "* Lütfen Bu Alanları Doldurunuz..";
            LblName.Text = "* Ad";
            LblName.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            LblWarning.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            break;
        case 4:
            LblWarning.Visible = true;
            LblWarning.Text = "* Lütfen Bu Alanları Doldurunuz..";
            LblSurname.Text = "* Soyad";
            LblSurname.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            LblWarning.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            break;
        case 5:
            LblWarning.Visible = true;
            LblWarning.Text = "* Lütfen Bu Alanları Doldurunuz..";
            LblDepartment.Text = "* Soyad";
            LblDepartment.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            LblWarning.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            break;
        case 6:
            LblFingerWarning.Visible = true;
            LblFingerWarning.Text = "Lütfen Parmak İzinizi Üç Kez Veriniz.";
            LblFingerWarning.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

However when user click Save button it will enter first IF condition. Then Else If .. But here is my problem. How i can organize these items. For example if user did't fill all boxes i want to give him all warning message not step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use if instead of else if because when first if is true it will not enter into else if, so only one message is displayed. Use it as :

```
     if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(TbTcNo.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TbTcNo.Text)))
        {
            warningcase = 1;
            TextLabelManagement(warningcase);                              
        }
        if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(TbId.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TbId.Text)))
        {
            warningcase = 2;
            TextLabelManagement(warningcase);               
        }
         if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(TbName.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TbName.Text)))
        {
            warningcase = 3;
            TextLabelManagement(warningcase);      
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a validator for text box. The validator controls that you would find in toolbox.

[Try the link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah5a961d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Winforms user control validation = http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229603(v=vs.110).aspx

ASP.NET  user control validation = http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kh55542.ASPX